# How to override the login process of Gnome/KDE?

Tags: linux, login

I would like to override the login process of my computer such that it could be logged in by a Bluetooth hardware security token instead of the typing username and password.

What would I need to do and where should I look to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

This will involve modifications to your PAM stack configuration.

To use a Bluetooth device, you probably want to look into http://blueproximity.sourceforge.net/manual.html

For an overview of PAM, I would refer you to http://pig.made-it.com/pam.html

Answer (score 2):

Ideally this would be done with a PAM module, I don't know if one is available for your hardware device.